# Color management in Fireworks CS6

Tags: color, cs6, adobe-fireworks

I'm using Fireworks for UI design. However, any saved `png` file from Fireworks shows different colors when opened in normal image viewers. Fireworks doesn't seem to have any color management options.

How can I make sure that the colors I'm looking at while designing will appear the same when the images are opened normally?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with CS5 and I found out that I had option Web colors checked, and this didn't allow me to set the colors that I wanted.

This might be possible solution.